# Rails collection check boxes set checkboxes as default checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have like to set all the check boxes here to be checked by default.  I tried a few methods from so but somehow could not get it to work.

```
  <div class="mr-6 text-xs">
        <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:clazz, @staff.clazzes.map { |c| 
              [ ' ' + c.name + ' ', c.id]
        }, :last, :first) %>
  </div>
```

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

The whole form looks like this:
https://gist.github.com/somaria/7d2bd484b8a45fa0623337ec397dfd3e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
<div class="mr-6 text-xs">
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:clazz, @staff.clazzes.map { |c| [ " #{c.name} ", c.id] }, :last, :first) do |b| %>
    <%= b.label { b.check_box(checked: true) + b.text } %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```